# A generalization of holomorphic functions

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus

Let's fix a  matrix $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.  Assume that the  following vector space of  smooth  functions is  closed under complex  multiplication:

$$\mathcal{S}_{A}=\{f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}\mid Df.A=A.Df  \}$$

Here  $Df$  is  the  Jacobian of  $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (We  identify  $\mathbb{C}$  with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$).

Does  this  imply that  $A$ is  in the  form $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&-b\\b&a \end{pmatrix}$?

Note that For $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$  the  relation $Df.A=A.Df$  is equivalent to the Cauchy Riemann equations for $f=u+iv$ so we obtain the class of  holomorphic  functions.

Comment: If it were termwise the commutivity condition would hold automatically.

Comment: @user1952009 In  $Df.A$ I  mean the  Matrix  multiplication. For that particular  matrix(corresponding  to $i$ in complex numbers) we obtain the  Cauchi Riemann equation)

Comment: (orthogonal means $M M^T = \lambda I$) if $A$ is orthogonal and not the identity then only the orthogonal matrices commute with $A$, so that $f$ is holomorphic ?

Comment: @user1952009  i  can not understand who your comment is related to my  question. But  I think that  your  comment  is  not  necessarily true:every  diagonal matrix commute with the orthogonal  matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$.rigth?

Comment: I meant $A$ orthogonal and not diagonal. And since it is $2 \times 2$ you can write directly the equation for $a,b,c,d$  such that $(a,b;c,d)$ commutes with $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. But the A is always satisfying Cauchy–Riemann equations.

Let $f = u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$,

By the definition of [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness): the f must be differentiable which implies f must satisfy Cauchy–Riemann equations.

For simplification: denote $$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = f_x$$

By [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations): $$u_x = v_y   \tag{1}$$ and $$u_y = - v_x \tag{2}$$

The Jacobian of f is $\begin{pmatrix} u_x&u_y\\v_x&v_y \end{pmatrix}$ Designate it as B.

Let A = $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$

Denote $U[i][j]$ is the entry on $i^{th}$ row $j^{th} $ column where U is a matrix;

By $A\times B =B\times A $

Then $(A\times B)[1][1] = au_x+bv_y=(B\times A)[1][1]  = au_x+cu_y $
By $(2)$,$ au_x+bu_y = au_x-bu_y$ forall $f$.

Thus $c = -b$.

Choose $(A\times B)[1][2] = (B\times A)[1][2] $ and using $(1)$, one can get d = a.

Choose  $(A\times B)[2][1] =  (B\times A)[2][1] $ one can show it has holed.

Choose  $(A\times B)[2][2] =  (B\times A)[2][2] $ one can show it has holed.

Thus A = $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: How does smoothness automatically imply satisfaction of CR? Am I missing something?

Comment: Smoothness means a function who has existence of continuous derivatives in arbitrary orders which shows that the derivatives in one order must exist. Since one-order derivative exist, CR automatically follows because of the differentiability. No, you aren't missing everything.

Comment: But say $f(x,y) = (x^2, y^2)$. This function is certainly smooth, but it does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Take for example, f(1,0) as an example, the derivative of (1,0) along real-axis is 2(i.e. ($x^2$)' = 2x ) and the derivative of (1,0) along imaginary-axis is 0 (i.e. ($y^2$)' = 2y ). What can you conclude about the derivative on point(1,0)? What's more, is it invalid the definition of smoothness?

Comment: For a more illustrative example, consider $f(x,y) = (2x + 2y, x + y)$. This function is smooth, but nowhere does it satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. All I'm saying is that there exist functions that are smooth but do not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Choose point (0,0) and in the same analogy, one can show the derivative of (0,0) along real-axis is 2. The derivative along imaginary-axis is 1. What's your conclusion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42206/discussion-between-zack-ni-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

Put $f(z)=z$ Then $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}_{A}$. So $f^{2}$ must belong to $\mathcal{S}_{A}$,too.
This means that $A$ commutes with all rotations. Hence $A$ has the desired representation as it is pointed out in the comment by user 1952009.